# Document.myform alternative js

Tags: javascript, forms

I have got a fully working js, but my problem is. I have do include it into a php file that generated by another programmer. The file is very huge and I can't rewrite everything.

In my js I use this: `document.myform1.cid.options[i].selected = true;`

But my problem that is the id of form is `createquestion-form`. And it has no name.

How could I `replace` `myform1` to `createquestion-form`?

This is my full script:

```
function Search()
            {
                var SearchKeyWord=document.getElementById("SearchText").value;
                var SelLength=document.myform1.cid.length;
                for(var i=0; i<SelLength;i++)
                {
                    var searched_text = document.myform1.cid.options[i].text;
                    var IsMatch = searched_text.search(SearchKeyWord);
                    if(IsMatch != -1)
                    {
                        document.myform1.cid.options[i].selected = true;
                        document.myform1.cid.options[i].style.color = 'red';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        document.myform1.cid.options[i].style.color = 'black';
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `document.getElementById`

```
form = document.getElementById('createquestion-form');
```